# Using AC_CONFIG_FILES to copy a file

Tags: autoconf

In my configure.ac file, I have this:

```
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile foo/bar.h],
  [mkdir -p ../dir1 && cp foo/bar.h ../dir1]
)
```

The goal is to:

- Generate the Makefile from Makefile.in
- Generate foo/bar.h from foo/bar.h.in
- Copy foo/bar.h to dir1/bar.h.

While it works, I'm pretty sure I've done that last part wrong.  Looking at the generated output, I see:

```
  case $ac_file$ac_mode in
    "Makefile":F) mkdir -p ../dir1 && cp foo/bar.h ../dir1
 ;;
    "foo/bar.h":F) mkdir -p ../dir1 && cp foo/bar.h ../dir1
 ;;

  esac
```

So it looks like it is doing my 'mkdir' command once for each file in the file list which is a bit redundant.  The fact that it does this in a 'case' statement suggests there is some way to specify commands to run specific to each file (otherwise why have a 'case'?).

What's the trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out I was misinterpreting what I was seeing.

Seeing that 'case' statement made me think there was some way to specify that some of the `cmds` applied to specific entries from the `files` parameter (something like [makefile:stuff1 foo/bar.h:stuff2]).  But (thankfully) that's not why the 'case' is there.

The trick here is that at the point where the case statement is produced, we *aren't* just walking the entries from AC_CONFIG_FILES `files`.  So in order to limit the `cmds` to the just AC_CONFIG_FILES entries, it uses a 'case.'

While my early attempts suggested that using two AC_CONFIG_FILES was not supported, that was wrong too.

My solution was to use 2 AC_CONFIG_FILES.

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't need to keep `bar.h` in the dir `foo`, I suppose you can do

```
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile bar.h:foo/bar.h.in])
```

source: https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Configuration-Files.html#Configuration-Files

In case bar.h needs to be in both locations and a link is acceptable, use

```
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile foo/bar.h])
AC_CONFIG_LINKS([bar.h:foo.bar.h])
```

source: https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Configuration-Links.html#Configuration-Links

Comment: While these would probably work, I ended up going a different way.